# how to have multiple values in the heading using XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="attribute[@name='Name']/value/datarow/cell[@name='fname'],[@name='lname']">

<xsl:value-of select="$age"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$address"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to have first name & last name to be the header following by age & address for each person.
How to get fname and lname concatenated with comma in the header?

Comment: Have a look for `concat()`. If that does not help. Please add input and expected output example.

Comment: My report should have the following:-........................................................                                        S.No. Name1's Age  Name1's Address  Name2's Age  Name2's Address...      1     Amit K 18    Amit K Chennai   Anil R  20   Anil R Pune                                              ....................................................................Here columns 2 & 3 corresponds to Name1. Name1 (Amit K) is the combination of FNAME - Amit and LNAME - K.  .........................Hope my Question is clear now. Please suggest.

Comment: Please edit your question: Put input and output there and format it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select=".">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(attribute[@name='Name']/value/datarow/cell[@name='fname'],[@name='lname'])" />
<xsl:value-of select="$age"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$address"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: My report should have the following:-

Comment: My report should have the following:-........................................................                                        S.No. Name1's Age  Name1's Address  Name2's Age  Name2's Address...      1     Amit K 18    Amit K Chennai   Anil R  20   Anil R Pune                                              ....................................................................Here columns 2 & 3 corresponds to Name1. Name1 (Amit K) is the combination of FNAME - Amit and LNAME - K.  .........................Hope my Question is clear now. Please suggest.

Comment: can you provide xml which you are trying